# getting only the outline of a scatter plot matlab

Tags: matlab, scatter, convex-hull

i'm trying to plot an outline of a scatter plot I have. I don't want any of the markers of the scatter only a line that outline the cloud of points and if at all possible to fill it with color. thanks!

```
    x = linspace(0,3*pi,200);
    y = cos(x) + rand(1,200);
    scatter(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to plot a [convex hull](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convex_hull) for which you can use the MATLAB [`convhull`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

Dan's answer is probably the best way to go.  Since it isn't clear whether you need a minimum hull or a spline-fit to the extreme points, I'll just suggest the latter as an option.  Roughly speaking, decide what a reasonable minimum radius should be, then scan from 0 to 2*pi , collecting the points of max radius (so long as that's greater than your selected minumum) at each sampled angle.  The fit a spline to that set of points.

This sort of problem can get extremely complicated, as in [this paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr11/cos598A/pdfs/Tagliasacchi09.pdf), BTW.

Edit: to answer Dan's question:
Matlab's got nothing builtin that I know of;  I would choose the center to be one of the centroids:  The mean `x`, `y` values of all points is a standard method.  If you have a theory as to the underlying distribution, e.g., 2D gaussian, you could try fitting the data to a distribution function and interpolating the centroid thereof.

Comment: That's an interesting method, does MATLAB have something like this pre-built? Also, how do you choose the center?